# GraphQL returns data but undefined in code

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am making a GraphQL request using below gql query.

```
export const GET_DETAILS = gql`
  query ($id: String) {
    country(id: $id) {
      currency
      phone
    }
  }
`;
```

When I check its response in network tab of chrome dev tools I see something below:

[dev tools image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qulyj.png)

But when I log it out in code below, it returns undefined.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Query query={GET_DETAILS} variables={{ id: `${this.props.match.params.code}` }}>
            {(loading, error, data) => {
              {console.log(data)} // ----> Here it is undefined

              return (
                <div>
                </div>
              );
            }}
        </Query>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong and how to fix?

Comment: Hey did you resolve? If yes, post the response.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario.

I copied a React component from one project to another, along with the **gql** query.

```
const { loading, data } = useQuery<NotificationsData>(GET_NOTIFICATIONS);
```

This was working fine on the older project and not in the new one. I could see the data being returned in the network tab, but it was still undefined in my component. Even when **loading** changed to false.

This was my **gql** query

```
query UserDetails {
  userDetails {
    id
    username
    first_name
    last_name
    avatar_url
    initials @client
  }
}
```

The issue here was the line

```
initials @client
```

so, i forgot to add the resolver for the **@client** field here, in my **index.tsx** file.

something like:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  resolvers: {
    UserEntity: {
      initials: (user, _args, { cache }) => {
        let initials = user.first_name[0];
        if (user.last_name && user.last_name.length) {
          initials = initials + user.last_name[0];
        }
        return initials;
      },
    },
  },
});
```

After adding this, the data started to show up just fine in my component.

Answer (score -1):

Like all API requests, GraphQL queries are asynchronous, so the data cannot be logged if it has not arrived from the server yet, which it looks like you are trying to do.

If you check to make sure the data exists before logging it it will work.

```
if (data) {
   console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The render props function used by the `Query` component is passed an object as its first and only parameter. `loading`, `error` and `data` are all properties on that object. In other words, using destructuring syntax, you can access them like this:

```
{({ loading, error, data }) => {
  console.log(data)
  ...
}
```

This is equivalent to

```
{(props) => {
  console.log(props.data)
  ...
}
```

Of course, because GraphQL requests are asynchronous, `data` will be undefined until the request completes so your code needs to reflect that fact as well.